# Trouble with for loop creating an archimedean spiral

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, infinite

I'm having trouble finding what's wrong with my program. When I execute it, it appears to get stuck into an infinite loop (or something similar) and I can't figure out what's wrong with my program. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class Spiral extends JComponent{

int WIDTH = 0;
int HEIGHT = 0;


public Spiral(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT) {
    this.WIDTH = WIDTH;
    this.HEIGHT = HEIGHT;
}


 public void paintSpiral(Graphics g){
    double a = 3;
    double b = 0;
    double t = 0;
    double theta = Math.toRadians(t);
    double r = theta * a + b;
    double pi = Math.PI/180;
    double end = 720 * pi;

    int middle_x = WIDTH / 2;
    int middle_y = HEIGHT / 2;

    for (theta = 0; theta < end; theta += pi) {
        double x = Math.cos(theta) * r + middle_x;
        double y = Math.sin(theta) * r + middle_y;
        int xx = (int) Math.round(x);
        int yy = (int) Math.round(y);
        g.drawLine(xx, yy, xx + 10, yy + 20);
    }


}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    paintSpiral(g);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1024;
    int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 1024;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    // Set the title of the window
    frame.setTitle("Archimedean Spiral");

    // Make a new Spiral, add it to the window, and make it visible
    Spiral d = new Spiral(1024, 1024);
    frame.add(d);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}

I have to use Graphics which is why I have the Math.round changing the x values to integers so I can actually draw the lines. That is what I suspect is the problem, but I can't seem to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: `Math.cos()` and `Math.sin()` are expecting inputs in Radians. It doesn't look like you're providing `t` as a radian value.

Answer (score 3):

The loop variable `t` is of type `int`, so `t += pi` is effectively a no-op, resulting in an infinite loop.

`t` should be of type `double`. Furthermore, it should be local to `paintSpiral` and not a member of the class. I don't understand why you're using `t` (which is zero) to initialize `r`.

Also, your degrees and radians seem all confused.

Comment: Thank you! My code now executes, but it seems to only execute once in the loop, not create a spiral like I want. I updated the code to show what I have now. All it prints out is a small line near the center of the window. I don't understand why the loop doesn't create a spiral?

Comment: Since `theta = Math.toRadians(t);` is `0` and `double r = theta * a + b;` which executes to `0*0+0`  => in your loop `x = Math.cos(theta) * r + middle_x;` executes to `x= 0+middle_x` .. the value of x never changes